# custom windows counter

Tags: java

I am writing a java application which generate integer values at times. The java application is running on Windows machine. I don't know if this is possible but I was wondering if I can create a Windows counter "MyCounter" for these values so that I can track
the "counter" in Windows Performances Monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's something that can be done in Java alone, but it could certainly be done using [JNI](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jni.html). The JNI mechanism lets Java code interface with platform native code, so you'd create the counter in C++ (for example) and then invoke that C++ code from Java through JNI. [JNA](http://jna.java.net/) is a  higher-lever layer on top of JNI which lets you do a lot of things on Windows without writing any native code yourself at all.

Comment: Hmm..I see, seems to be quite complex to achive

Answer (score 1):

For Java applications it's standard to use [JMX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/javamanagement-140525.html) if you want to offer some monitoring for your application. Otherewise [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-2004/jw-1108-windowspm.html) is a tutorial for accessing windows performance counters from Java.